# Using the Solr API, how do I set a defined field to the unique key?

Tags: api, solr

I'm implementing a version 7.5 Solr indexing system.  I have successfully created the core, created field types, and created fields all using the API posting JSON.

How can I now set one of my defined fields to be the unique key, also using the API?

Answer (score 2):

It's [currently not possible to set the unique key (SOLR-7242)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7242) through the Schema API.

Manually changing the definition in your schema file is still how you'll have to do it.